# Working with NumPy structured arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

I am working with a NumPy structured array with the following structure:

```
ar = np.array([(760., 0), (760.3, 0), (760.5, 0), (280.0, 1), (320.0, 1), (290.0, 1)], dtype=[('foo', 'f4'),('bar', 'i4')])
```

What is an efficient way of extracting the 'foo' fields for a specific value of 'bar'? For example, I would like to store all the 'foo' values for which 'bar' is 0 in an array:

```
fooAr = ar['foo'] if ar['bar'] is 0
```

The above does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ar['foo'][ar['bar'] == 0]`:

```
ar = np.array([(760., 0), (760.3, 0), (760.5, 0), (280.0, 1), (320.0, 1), (290.0, 1)], dtype=[('foo', 'f4'),('bar', 'i4')])

print(ar['bar'] == 0)
# array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

result = ar['foo'][ar['bar'] == 0]
print(result)
# array([ 760.        ,  760.29998779,  760.5       ], dtype=float32)
```

Note that since a boolean selection mask, `ar['bar'] == 0`, is used, `result` is a *copy* of parts of `ar['foo']`. 
Thus, modifying `result` would not affect `ar` itself.

---

To modify `ar` assign to `ar['foo'][mask]` directly:

```
mask = (ar['bar'] == 0)
ar['foo'][mask] = 100

print(ar)
# array([(100.0, 0), (100.0, 0), (100.0, 0), (280.0, 1), (320.0, 1), (290.0, 1)], 
#        dtype=[('foo', '<f4'), ('bar', '<i4')])
```

Assignment to `ar['foo'][mask]` calls `ar['foo'].__setitem__` which affects `ar['foo']`. 
Since `ar['foo']`  is a *view* of `ar`, modifying `ar['foo']` affects `ar`.

---

Note that **the order of indexing matters** here. If you tried applying the boolean mask
before selecting the `'foo'` field, as in:

```
ar[mask]['foo'] = 99
```

Then this would **not** affect `ar`, since `ar[mask]` is a *copy* of `ar`.
Nothing done to the copy (`ar[mask]`) affects the original (`ar`).